# Test whether a Django migration has been applied to a DB

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have a django project, and I wish to update a MySQL database from a previous version of the codebase to be compatible with the current version.

I have all of the migrations for the project, but I do not know which was the last one applied to this alternate database.

I can try and determine this manually, but I was wondering if there was an easier automated way of finding which the first unapplied migration is.

Comment: There is a migrations table that lists the status of every migration

Answer (score 3):

You can work with the [**`showmigrations`** command <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-showmigrations), this will generate a list of the migrations where it will check a box in case that migration has been applied, so:

```
python3 manage.py showmigrations
```

or for a specific app:

```
python3 manage.py showmigrations app_name
```

For example for `auth`, a possible result is:

```
$ python manage.py showmigrations auth
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [ ] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [ ] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
```

This thus means that all migrations have been applied, except the last two.

Comment: That's extremely helpful and I think answers the question, thank you.
Unfortunately in my specific case it doesn't think any of the migrations have been applied, so something's gone wrong somewhere.  I guess I may need to nuke it.

Comment: @Omroth: Django keeps a table `django_migrations` that keeps track of what migrations have been applied. You thus should not mess with that table, since then Django will no longer know what has been applied.